# Array.reduce and a weird error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a problem when I read blog about Javascript Array.reduce function,the code is:

```
var res = str.split('')
         .reduce((pre, cur) => (pre[cur]++ || (pre[cur] = 1), pre), {});
```

I don't know why arrow function has two return express, In other words, i thought it should be:

```
var res = str.split('')
         .reduce((pre, cur) => (pre[cur]++ || (pre[cur] = 1), {});
```

what's the difference?
then I try to rebuild the function as:

```
var res = str.split('')
        .reduce(function(pre,cur){
         console.log(pre) ;
         console.log(cur) ;
         if( pre[cur] === 1)
         {
          pre[cur]++;
         } else
           pre[cur] = 1;
        }, {});
```

but I get error again,and the error is so weird!!!:

```
             if( pre[cur] === 1)
                    ^
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined

what? property 'd'?

Could you please answer my two questions?

Comment: it's comma operator. and reduce function need to return result (`pre` in your case)

Comment: Adding to what @Maxx said, Value of `pre` is being manipulated by what is being returned in `Array#reduce`. If you do not return, `pre` is not an `object` anymore.. With `comma operator`, last value after `comma` is returned..

Comment: I mean ,Arrow function should be use as (param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression,why  (pre[cur]++ || (pre[cur] = 1), pre)?  two expressions?@Rayon @Maxx

Comment: @Archsx `(pre[cur]++ || (pre[cur] = 1), pre)` is not arguments of arrow function, it's body of it. it's one expression with comma operator. coma operator just evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last

Comment: I know the argument is pre and cur,but I still don't know this way of using Arrow function,I thought there should only be one express. thx anyway @Maxx

Comment: Sry, I learn coma operator from MDN, problem solved,thank you so much!  @Maxx

Answer (score 1):

This

```
var res = str.split('')
     .reduce((pre, cur) => (pre[cur]++ || (pre[cur] = 1), pre), {});
```

equals

```
var res = str.split('')
     .reduce(function(pre, cur){
         if (!pre[cur]++) {
             pre[cur] = 1;
         }
         return pre;
     }, {});
```

Comment: Thx, I haven't known this way about Arrow function before.